# SQL Join not filtering as expected SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have this query & what I need is to return contributions associated with agreements and applications but exclude the contributions where the agreement is not in the correct status

```
select * from contributions c
left join agreements as ag on ag.Id = c.AgreementId and ag.status in (1,2,3,4)
left join applications as ap on ap.Id = c.ApplicationId
```

This current query is excluding the agreement detail but still returning the contribution row. I'm not sure if the 'and' clause is doing what I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude the record from the main table using the `OUTER JOIN'ed table` then you need to use the condition in the `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
select * from contributions c
left join agreements as ag on ag.Id = c.AgreementId 
left join applications as ap on ap.Id = c.ApplicationId
where ag.status in (1,2,3,4) or ag.status is null
```

This will return all the `contributions` for which either `agreement` do not exist or if an `agreement` exists then the `agreement` should have `status` in `1,2,3,4`

Comment: I didn't have the null check when I tried moving the where clause so was getting unexpected results! Thanks for the answer